# How can I add an outlet to a switch box?

Tags: wiring

I have a three-gang box and wish to take out one switch and add a double switch, eliminating one switch.  I'd like to use the space of the eliminated switch for a outlet. There is already a GFCI in this bathroom. The neutrals are all together on one circuit.

How do I use the hot wires to connect all of the switches and outlet? By the way, one other switch will remain for the fan.

[image]

Comment: Have you determined which black is your incoming hot? The rest are jumpers to other switches and returns to the light. You need to identify the source cable.

Comment: Yes, I did.  Now I am thinking connect the hot to the double switch, black screw, then connect the othe black(s) to the brass screw.  The hot went to the fan.  Or, do I pig tail the hot from the fan to the black double switch screw?

Comment: By the way this circuit is connected to my basement lights.

Comment: Aside: We have a duplex receptacle with one side always-on and the other controlled by an adjacent timer: [receptacle image](https://www.enerlites.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/6/3/63150-tr-plh-w_0001.jpg). The markings clarify that one side might not work all of the time. Our friendly local building inspector had no idea of what it was. At least the education wasn't painful.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pull a cable over from the GFCI on the other side of the vanity?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have this scenario. You'd just connect the hot and neutral to the new outlet, and pigtail to the various switches. Blacks go out from the switches to the light or fan, and whites return to the neutral bundle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Make Sure You Have GFCI Protection

> There is already a GFCI in this bathroom

That is actually *almost* irrelevant. The rule isn't "you must have at least one GFCI-protected receptacle in the bathroom". It is two *separate* rules:

- You must have at least one receptacle in the bathroom (and powered only with other stuff in that bathroom or receptacles in another bathroom, but that is a capacity issue, which is a separate discussion, though it is a *possible* issue here because of "connected to my basement lights").
- **Every** ordinary receptacle in the bathroom (there may be exceptions if you have a ceiling receptacle for lighting, which you really shouldn't do, but I'm not sure...for practical purposes "all receptacles") must be GFCI-protected.

The protection can be provided at the receptacle (which I think is what you meant in your original statement), at *another* receptacle properly wired earlier in the circuit, with a GFCI-only device somewhere earlier in the circuit (in the same bathroom or another bathroom), or with a GFCI-breaker in the panel.

The *usual* setup is GFCI-receptacle because that is easy to retrofit and convenient. You have one of those. But this new receptacle **must** also be protected. Since this circuit is also powering lights, and since pulling power from the lighting circuit is far easier than connecting to the existing bathroom receptacle circuit, and since putting the entire circuit (i.e., including lighting) on GFCI has other problems (basement goes dark when GFCI trips), the simple solution is to **install a GFCI-receptacle** here instead of a plain receptacle. This is not just a good idea, it is code. In fact, someone used to "multiple GFCI-receptacles in a  bathroom chained together and trip/reset together" would be left with a potentially fatal false sense of security seeing one receptacle with GFCI and one without.